# Get shorted string from fullname with C#

Tags: c#

Please help me with c#
to convert list of fullname
Table 1:

```
Hoang Hai
Hoang Vu Hiep
Nguyen Tat Loc
Pham Manh Quan
Nguyen Tien Sy
Bui Duc Tai
Lu Quoc Duc
Do Van Hung
Pham Thi Thuy Ngan
Nguyen Van Ngoc
...
```

Expected Output:

```
H.Hai
V.Hiep
T.Loc
M.Quan
T.Sy
D.Tai
Q.Duc
V.Hung
T.Ngan
V.Ngoc
...
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow. You should include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: To get you started: You could loop through the lines of text, [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.String.Split);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) based on the space `(' ')`, Check to see if you have at least two element and if so, do a [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) on the length-2 element. From there you can just concatenate the result of the substring with a `.` and the length-1 element of the split.

Answer (score 0):

*** on your list, there must be only one (' ') space char between the first name and last name*** like this=> "Jing Jan"

```
 var mylst = new List<string> { "Hoang Hai", "Pham Manh", "Thuy Ngan", "Bui Duc" };
        for (var index = 0; index < mylst.Count; index++)
        {
            var itemsplited = mylst[index].Split(' ');
            mylst[index] = itemsplited[0].ToUpper()[0] + "." + itemsplited[1];
        }
```

Comment: What if there is more than one `' '`, like in most of the names? Anyway, you shouldn't answer questions that show no effort, because OP could be encouraged to ask such questions.

Comment: you can use a trim method. thanks for your advice sir.